# Dynamic criteria in Grails controller's index action

Tags: grails, controller, criteria

I am trying to alter the default index action for a Grails controller to enable some basic search criteria.

I have two main issues:

1. The paginate control at the bottom of the page forgets my search criteria.
2. How can I use the grails criteria `createCriteria().list()` operation with variable criteria. In particular, how should I account for things like `null` (ignored) criteria?

edit: I am adding my controller code:

```
    def index(Integer max) {
        session.alarmFilter = params.alarmFilter == null ? (session.alarmFilter == null ? [] : session.alarmFilter) : params.alarmFilter
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        def c = Alarm.createCriteria()
        def results = c.list (params) {
            if(session?.alarmFilter?.channelInterface != null) {
                sqlRestriction("channel_interface_id = ${session.alarmFilter.channelInterface.id}")
            }
        }
        respond results, model:[alarmFilter: session.alarmFilter, alarmInstanceCount: results.totalCount]
    }
```

I'm not fond of saving the search criteria (alarmFilter) in the session since it doesn't really feel like session information. In particular, returning to this page will remember previous search criteria.

Also the `if` statement is causing an 'SQLException' when the criteria is not selected.